# Reading array in php

Tags: php, arrays, web-crawler

I'm making a crawler, just trying out the basics. I get stuck at trying to echo the array that I get from the crawler. This is the array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => vageemail@hotmail.com ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Testemail@hotmail.com ) )
```

And I want to echo this:

```
vageemail@hotmail.com
Testemail@hotmail.com
```

So what I did is this:

```
$teller = 1;
while ( $teller != 10 ) {
    foreach ( $email[$teller] as $mail ) {
        echo $mail;
        $teller = $teller + 1;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $a)
    echo $a[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it display an error message? If so, what is it?

Also, the while loop is pretty much useless as foreach loop acts as a "while loop" until it has iterated through the entire array.

Answer (score 0):

Your array starts on `0`.
Assuming that `$emails` is your array.

```
foreach ( $emails as $email ) {
   foreach ( $email as $mail ) {
      echo $mail;       
   }    
}
```

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/testos.php

Comment: This happens because you iterate thrue an undefined index, use `foreach` instead of `while`